# how to debug "sql subquery returns more than 1 row" error

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

We have a huge SQL script involving tens of tables, subqueries, hundreds of attributes. It works perfectly in the test database but returns `sql subquery returns more than 1 row` error when running in the production database. The script was working perfectly up until now. The problem is, all I get is a one-line error specified above with no clues whatsoever which exact subquery causes the error which makes it near to impossible to debug. The question is, how am I supposed to know which line of the SQL causes the error? Is there any way to "debug" it line by line like you would do it in a programming language? 
I am using TOAD with Oracle 11g.

Comment: Search for `...=(select...)` locations in your script.

Comment: The script is huge, I mean huge. It would be very time consuming to search every single subquery. Some of the subqueries are correlated subqueries which makes them even harder to understand. A select clause on line 100 references a table on line 800 for instance. That's why I need to know which subquery causes the error so that I can try to correct it. Or at least, at which point of the execution the error pop ups, meaning which data causes the subquery to return more than one row.

Comment: "It works perfectly in the test database"; so there's two options here. Either you have a data problem in your prod database (i.e. some missing keys etc) in which case you need to fix that. Check all the constraints on all the table associated with this query. The other option is that your test DB didn't have the correct data in which case this query is incorrect and was never working. The simplest way to debug this sort of thing is to take a minimal part of the query and build upon it... keep adding more and more until you hit the error.

Comment: There is no good answer I'm afraid. If you've an old version of the script which didnt produce the error you can investigate the changes made which now result in the error; Aside from that you basically need to copy it and iteratively remove subqueries from it until you find the problem. However my observation would be that if it is as huge as you say, the script might be better reorganised to use a series of smaller queries, each doing less work, & producing temporary tables, which are used by later queries to deliver the same end result; This logic is a lot easier when problems arise.

Comment: Temporary tables are rarely a good idea in Oracle @John. They're used more for complex processes rather than queries as in T-SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `print` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` commands to your script to print messages.  And/or use exception handlers in the script.  Possibly add some variables that count or label which statement you are at, and output that in the exception handler.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm

Once you have found the query that causes the problem, convert it to a similar query with an appropriate `group by` and `having count(*) > 1` so that you can see what data caused the problem.  For instance if you have a correlated subquery that looks like:

```
(select name from names where id=foo.id)
```

then write a similar query

```
select id from names group by id having count(*) > 1
```

to identify the offending data.

If you have multiple subqueries in the query that produces the error, you could temporarily convert the subqueries to use temporary tables and search them all for duplicates.

Comment: Some examples would be nice, don't just say "Use print or dbms_output"